# How do they create so small OS images?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-container, docker-image

Apparently OS distributions come in stripped down versions. E.g. ubuntu for docker is ~150MB which is quite small. But I don’t understand how can it be so small. Do they ship the most minimal functionality and expose fake APIs that delegate to the host kernel? How do they make it so small?

Comment: Why do you think an minimal OS would need more than 150 MB?

Comment: Much of the heavy stuff is UI related which you don't need in a docker image.

Comment: When they strip, they usually tag it `slim`, like Debian. Otherwise image contains everything but GUI features

Comment: It's a standard setup, using unmodified GNU libc, that talks directly to the host kernel; I wouldn't call it "fake" or "delegated".  Many images like to use https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/ as their base which comes in around 5 MB, but is still perfectly functional.

Comment: So e.g. all networking stuff are included in the stripped version?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.